# Suppress warning when sourcing sql file back to mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysqldump -udbuser -pAdmin@123 -h192.167.93.44 -P32083 --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=OFF --databases mohwscdrdb mohwsecsdb moresourcelifecycledb moorderdb movdcservicedb > ./backup.sql 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning"
```

That was run as I thought, without **"Warnning: using password.."** blablabla.

But when I execute:

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysql -udbuser -pAdmin@123 -h192.167.93.44 -P32083 < ./backup.sql 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning"
```

in order to source back the sql file without warnning, it fails, saying:

```
/' at line 1
```

I think it was because I have **two different redirect directions** (`<` and `>`) in one line, but how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`2>&1` ties both file descriptors together. You only want to grep on stderr so by using '|&' only the stderr goes to grep.

So on dumping:

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysqldump ... movdcservicedb > ./backup.sql |& grep -v "Warning"
```

Comment: @danblank, thanks for you answer, but here what I want is to make the second shell command run correctly..

Answer (score 0):

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysqldump -udbuser -pAdmin@123 **> ./backup.sql** 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning"
```

**change the order， moving the redirecting part to the end of the command, will make the thing done.**

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysqldump -udbuser -pAdmin@123 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning" **> ./backup.sql**
```

**by the way, importing sql should keep the `< ./backup.sql` in the middle of the command.**

```
/opt/mysql/bin/mysql -udbuser -pAdmin@123 < ./backup.sql 2>&1 | grep -v "Warning"
```